# Dataflow (Beam 2.12) does not start due to ext4 not found

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am seeing all types of strange errors when running a dataflow job (Beam 2.12).

The job basically takes input from pubsub, read/writes from/to Datastore writes the result to pubsub.

Several Warnings `W` and Errors `E` appear in the Stackdriver logs. It is unclear how to resolve these. Up to now we were using Beam 2.9 and were not experiencing any of these issues.

A partial (redacted) log dump is available below.

```
W  acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge. 
W  ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11 
W  ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 10 
W  i8042: Warning: Keylock active 
W  GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk. 
W  GPT:52428799 != 62914559 
W  GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk. 
W  GPT:52428799 != 62914559 
W  GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors. 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 0: 'payload=PARTUUID=XXX' 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 1: 'hashtree=PARTUUID=XXX' 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 2: 'hashstart=2539520' 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 3: 'alg=sha1' 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 4: 'root_hexdigest=900...' 
W  device-mapper: verity: Argument 5: 'salt=b113702...' 
W  [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:12] Duplicate line for path "/var/run", ignoring. 
W  Cannot set file attribute for '/var/log/journal', value=0x00800000, mask=0x00800000: Operation not supported 
W  Cannot set file attribute for '/var/log/journal/2a0c3f0af65e8318a0b8f3eb...', value=0x00800000, mask=0x00800000: Operation not supported 
W  Could not load the device policy file. 
W  [WARNING:persistent_integer.cc(96)] cannot open /var/lib/metrics/version.cycle for reading: No such file or directory 
W  WARNING Could not update the authorized keys file for user root. [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/root/.ssh'. 
W  [CLOUDINIT] cc_write_files.py[WARNING]: Undecodable permissions None, assuming 420 
...
E  Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system 
W  No api server defined - no node status update will be sent. 
W  Failed to retrieve checkpoint for "kubelet_internal_checkpoint": checkpoint is not found 
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container 7df5acdbd1ad6756e3e409c6e8760d274bdc03f83bf... 
E  while reading 'google-dockercfg-url' metadata: http status code: 404 while fetching url http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/google-dockercfg-url 
E  while reading 'google-dockercfg' metadata: http status code: 404 while fetching url http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/google-dockercfg 
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container 3aa8c92a0b7d746d7004768d5182f0558a0c0c90dfcd5... 
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container 64b9fb0459f88833dee78943c32598761154e4a49d708... 
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container d2edf1c5e89b746e8c9c96b2a39a9d7ac7da2ecf52f96d...
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container b2448a8792ad63059bb70f1f6f12385caae7a833018d05...
E  EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem 
E  Error syncing pod c386113... ("dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=java-streaming pod=dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)" 
W  [WARNING:metrics_daemon.cc(619)] cannot read /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq 
E  EXT4-fs (sdd): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem 
...
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container 675eb66a9e794b3dea03b62c3bdaf539034c998bf11c... 
E  Error syncing pod c386113... ("dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=java-streaming pod=dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)" 
E  Error syncing pod c386113... ("dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=java-streaming pod=dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)" 
E  Error syncing pod c386113... ("dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=java-streaming pod=dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)" 
W  Unknown healthcheck type 'NONE' (expected 'CMD') in container 7d7536b93cb92562bdd12da3fd25a53caea8c9a9e1cee603b3999dfdd5681a27 
E  Error syncing pod c386113... ("dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=java-streaming pod=dataflow-...-harness-z656_default(c386113...)"
```

Comment: I see "kubernetes" there;  file system is read-only. What is your job doing?

Comment: Basically just taking input from pubsub, doing datastore IO and writing to pubsub. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by upgrading several dependencies.

The maven versions plugin helped me do this, I installed the plugin by adding the following to my `.pom` file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
```

Then I checked the libraries to update and updated them. I suspect it to be an older BigTable client, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/2151).

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
mvn versions:use-latest-versions
```